# Python - removing xml tag in an element

Tags: python, xml

I am using python 2.7.2. and dom parser to read the data on several xml files. And export .db file to use on sql server. I have learned how to export the files, but XML tags are also included on my data tables. Here is the basic code :

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import sqlite3
xmldoc = minidom.parse('c:\dd\l2con\l2connection.xml')
coId = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('id')
```

and each element are like this :

```
>>> coId[0]
<DOM Element: id at 0x249cf30>
>>> print coId[0].toxml()
<id>45859</id>
>>> coId[1]
<DOM Element: id at 0x24ac328>
>>> print coId[1].toxml()
<id>46889</id>
>>>
```

where they should look like this: without the xml tags

```
>coId[0].toxml()
45859
>coId[1].toxml()
46889
```

Deleting the tags from xml probably won't work for this case.This way python can't read the xml file. Is there any way you can advise me on this subject.Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Yusuf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coId[0]` is a DOM Element with one child (a [Text](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#text-and-cdatasection-objects) node). Use

```
coId[0].firstChild.data
```

to get the text content.

This works too:

```
coId[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

Comment: thank you
I have the correct values now.

` >>> coId[0].firstChild.data
u'45859'
>>> coId[0].firstChild.nodeValue
u'45859' `

Answer (score 2):

use `coId[0].data` instead, this gives the element content.

*See [mzjn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680413/python-removing-xml-tag-in-an-element/6684434#6684434), coId[0].firstChild.data is the correct way to do it.*

Comment: This can't work. DOM `Element` instances do not have a `data` attribute.

Comment: Elements have a `nodeValue` attribute, but it returns `None`.

Comment: OK, linked to your answer then.

Comment: coId[0].data gives this error.
`AttributeError: Element instance has no attribute`
.data worked for other elements in similar project
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use/try the `nodeValue` attribute

Let's assume that you have:

```
myNode.toXml()= <name>Ben</name>
```

then

```
myNode.nodeValue = Ben
```